# “Hic” or “hīc”?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

The pronoun ***hic*** (this) is written with short *i* in many places, e.g. *Oxford Latin Dictionary*. But in Lewis & Short: *Latin-English dictionary* and *Allen and Greenough's New Latin Grammar*, it is written as ***hīc*** with a long *i*.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vowel in the pronoun *hic* is certainly short, but in poetry the word often (not always!) scans as long even when it is followed by a vowel, as if it were actually *hicc*. This is not etymologically defensible, but it happens in analogy with the neuter nom./acc. sg. *hо̆c* (which L&S also has as *hōc* despite its short vowel), which is always *hocc* when followed by a vowel (in pronunciation and scansion if not in actual writing), because it reflects an older pronoun **hod* + the deictic particle *-c(e)* (also seen in e.g. *illic* (*ille* + *-c*), *tunc* (*tum* + *-c*)), with assimilation of the *d* to the *c*.
The resulting geminate consonant disappears phonotactically when followed by a consonant or hiatus, which is presumably why it isn't written, but it's still lurking underneath. *hic* reflects **hĭ* + the same particle and so doesn't genuinely/originally have the geminate, but it does show up.

L&S, like a lot of older works, uses macrons to indicate syllable weight, not vowel length. It's often the same thing, but not in this case.

(The adverb *hīc* does have a genuine long vowel, and so do some of the (other) declined forms of the pronoun.)